# 2 Google Glasses, ADB sees one but not the other?

Tags: google-glass

I am trying to side-load an apk onto a friend's Google Glass to test my app.  I'm using a machine running Windows 8.  The Glass drivers are properly configured on the machine because I am able to connect to and side-load apps to my personal glass, which is running XE12.

I have turned on debug on his device which also has XE12.  When I plug in my Google Glass, "adb devices" returns the serial number as expected, so I know the problem is not the machine, cable, or theoretically the driver.  When I unplug mine and plug his in, adb does not see it.  I have tried killing/restarting the adb server.  I tried going through the driver install process while his was connected, but no luck.  I've tried restarting his Glass.  I can connect to his device on a Mac with adb, so I know it is not the device. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more detail about what you've tried on Glass and on your computer? Also, are both devices the same hardware revision?

Comment: Added more detail as requested.  They are both running XE12, both gen2 hardware.  The strange thing is I can communicate with it on a Mac at work, so the issue is Windows specific.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
adb shell kill-server
adb shell start-server
```

my adb has trouble when I swap android devices plugging/unplugging in another device especially my glass.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that with no luck.  I was able to connect to the device on a Mac, so the problem is Windows-specific (surprise).